# get the CSS maxWidth value of the parent javascript

Tags: javascript, css, parent-child

I have these elements:

`<div class="parent"><div class="child"></div></div>`

css:
 `.parent{max-width:100px}`

Is it possible to get "max-width" value specified in css using "parentNode" of "child" (the name of parent is unpredictable) in order to compare it with the current variable data?

I was trying:

```
var childDIV=querySelector('.child');
var result= childDIV.parentNode.style.maxWidth`
```

"result" is empty.

Another attempt was using "getComputedStyle" method:

```
var result =window.getComputedStyle(childDIV.parentNode,null);
result.getPropertyValue("maxWidth");
```

"result" is empty although proper "maxWidth" value shows up among values of "getComputedStyle"  .

```js
var childDIV=document.querySelector('.child');
var result= childDIV.parentNode.style.maxWidth;
console.log(`Approach 1: ${result}`);

var result =window.getComputedStyle(childDIV.parentNode,null);
result = result.getPropertyValue("maxWidth");
console.log(`Approach 2: ${result}`);
```

```css
 .parent{max-width:100px}
```

```html
<div class="parent"><div class="child"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were on the right track - so, your first approach does not work in this case because the element doesn't have `max-width` directly inside its style declaration (see sample below with `.other` for when this *would* work).

The second approach is correct, but you mixed up access argument a little - if you use `.getPropertyValue`, you use CSS-style `"max-width"`, and if you don't, you use `.maxWidth` like with `.style`:

```js
var childDIV=document.querySelector('.child');

var result= document.querySelector('.other').style.maxWidth;
console.log(`Approach 1: ${result}`);

var compStyle = window.getComputedStyle(childDIV.parentNode,null);

result = compStyle.maxWidth;
console.log(`Approach 2: ${result}`);

result = compStyle.getPropertyValue("max-width");
console.log(`Approach 3: ${result}`);
```

```css
.parent{max-width:100px}
```

```html
<div class="parent"><div class="child"></div></div>

<div class="other" style="max-width:50px"></div>
```